# Accepting keyboard shortcuts when not in focus

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

Is it possible to have my app running in the system tray, but still accepting keyboard input, even when it is being typed into another application? Don't worry, I'm not making a shady evil keylogger :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create non window bound keyboard shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598895/how-to-create-non-window-bound-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Do you just want a (few) global hotkey(s), or want to get all keyboard input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. You can register a [hotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [hook the keyboard](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS406US406&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+keyboard+hook).

Comment: Registering the hotkey is preferred when possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hotkey seems great!

Comment: @JJ56, no problem. If you go the hotkey route, I'd recommend using this: http://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/

Comment: @CodeInChaos, maybe not, but did you look at the actual class he wrote? Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: An operator precedence bug, lack of thread safety, bad finalization pattern, throwing the wrong kind of exception... In addition the id allocation patters may only used in applications in that way. For libraries you should use the ID of a global atom you create in order to ensure uniqueness.